# Filter queryset using child object fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two models Parent, Child

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(...)

class Child(models.Model)
    id = models.IntegerField(...)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, ...)
    wanted = models.CharField(default="yes")
```

I want to filter all Parent objects where all the children present with that parent will have 'wanted' as 'yes'

My code:

```
    def containsYes(self):
        yes_ids = []
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        for q in qs:
            children = Child.objects.filter(parent_id = q.id)
            count = children .count()
            if children.filter(wanted = 'yes').count() == count
            yes_ids.append(q.id)
        return qs.filter(id__contains = yes_ids)
```

I know that this code is dead inefficient, and want a better solution using only querys

PS: Im new to django

Answer (score 1):

We can exclude `Parent`s where there exists a child that is not wanted, so we can work with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Count, Q

Parent.objects.annotate(
    nchild=Count('child')
    nchild_wanted=Count('child', filter=Q(child__wanted=True))
).filter(
    nchild=F('nchild_wanted')
)
```

We thus first count the number of related `Child`s, and also the number of related `Child`s with `wanted` is set to `True`. Then we filter and only retain `Parent` objects where these two annotations are the same.

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), one can make use of [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent counting both in the `SELECT` clause and the `HAVING` clause:

```
from django.db.models import F, Count, Q

Parent.objects.alias(
    nchild=Count('child')
    nchild_wanted=Count('child', filter=Q(child__wanted=True))
).filter(
    nchild=F('nchild_wanted')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give a parent related name in child model:

parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, ..., related_name=“children”)

2. Change Wanted field to boolean and default it to True, than you can do the following:

Parent.objects.filter(children__wanted=True).exclude(children__wanted =False)

Or you can call Parent.objects.exclude(children__wanted=False) case this boolean is not nullable field.

Comment: This will return all `Parent`s for which there *exists* a child that is wanted, not all children. So a `Parent` with two children, one wanted, and another not wanted will be retrieved by the queryset.